# OS X application menu bar not showing correct title

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a OS X application.  The app works fine, and the first menu item is the app's title, "Elision".  However, under the "Elision" and "Help" menus, the title displayed is "Test".  How do I change this?
[image][image]

Comment: Create a new project with the correct name

Comment: @LeoDabus but I never changed the name-the project started with the current name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **xib** or **storyboard** file containing the menu, and select the menu item(s) you wish to change. You may set the menu item titles as desired via the Inspector:
[image]